# MVC fields not required but user being told they are

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Title says it all. The model does not require the StartDate field but on POST I'm told it's required. It's one of several search fields, each one optional. Due to that, I'm not checking IsModel.Valid so the search works anyway, but the message shows up onscreen. If I set, in the view, @Html.ValidationSummary(true), that hides the message but the field still turns red.

Also, I do have a check to make sure EndDate is later than StartDate, so I need the messages for errors /requried fields to show up, just not when there ISN'T an error.

Here's the code:

MODEL (Partial)

```
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "End Date")]
    [GreaterThanOrEqualTo("StartDate", ErrorMessage = "End Date must be later than Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

VIEW (partial)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){ 
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.StartDate)
        @Html.TextBox("StartDate", "", new { @class = "datefield" })

etc.
```

SHARED/DISPLAY TEMPLATES

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
@(Model != null ? string.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", Model) : string.Empty)
```

SHARED/EDITOR TEMPLATES

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
 @{
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
if (Model != null)
{
   dt  = (System.DateTime) Model;

}
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
}
```

Some of these editors are to make a pop-up calendar work, btw.

I've tried turning on/off various things and one way or another, it still says the date fields are required. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try making it nullable?

Comment: And if that isn't it, does another partial exist with a metadata attribute?

Comment: Thanks so far. Making it nullable partly solved that. I can submit TWO nulls, but not only StartDate and null EndDate because the EndDate must be later.

Comment: You really have two validations here.  You cannot perform logic like that in the standard attributes.  You would have to write a custom validation to deal with conditional situations.  You could also use IValidatableObject, or something like FluentValidation.

Comment: Not sure, but try removing [DataType(DataType.Date)]. Could be that this is enforcing it to be required, not null, and of type dateTime.

Comment: I wrote an attribute to handle the 'one must be later than the other' deal

Answer (score 7):

Easy way to remove validation is make int Null-able, I have already tested and it works fine. here is example:

```
 public int? Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, value types like DateTime, int, decimal, etc. are treated as required if you don't make them nullable.

If the GreaterThanOrEqualTo attribute doesn't come from a library (such as MVC Foolproof Validation), you should let it return true if both Startdate en Enddate are null. Else you woud have to write your own custom validation attribute, but it's not that hard to do.

Comment: When used in a comlplex ViewModel, values like int work just fine without having to be nullable if you use get;set; properties as the initializer sets it to a default value of 0 anyways.

Comment: It is from MVC Foolproof validation. Not so foolproof, as it turns out. I just wrote a simple check on POST.